# Modify HTML according to provided JQuery Snippet

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to modify my HTML for according to class names in following jQuery Snippet. The snippet add class to texarea which turns border red

JQuery Snippet:

```
$(".scope-question .commentbox").removeClass("redColor")
$(".scope-question input[data-require-comment]:checked").each(function() {
$(this).closest(".scope-question").find(".commentbox").addClass("redColor");
});
```

Fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/t23un23y/

There are four questions, with 3 radio box as answer(Yes/No/Not Applicable) and a textarea for remarks. On Click of particular radio, Say NO, the textarea border turns red.

I am trying to modify HTML, using class names given in above snippet. Unable to get desire output. Could anyone please help in same.

**Update**: 
1) if not necessary; please try not to modify JQuery code;  but HTML Code as on particular click i need some changes in whole question row like grey of question, disable other radio etc.

2) I have just created fiddle for onClick of radio, i have use case to validate red color textarea on load too. So please also consider the case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated Fiddle: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/t23un23y/1/)

Basically, your code assumes that `.scope-question` is a parent of the inputs, when in fact it is a sibling of their parents.

```
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function () {
    var textarea = $(this).closest("div").next(".scope-question").find(".commentbox");
    if($(this).val() === "No") {
        textarea.addClass("redColor");
    }
    else {
        textarea.removeClass("redColor");
    }
});
```

**Update**

[Detailed Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t23un23y/7/)

Here's a summary of the changes I made:

1. Updated the HTML to use `.scope-question` as a wrapper
2. Added `data-require-comment` attribute to the "NO" radio buttons.

   - I'm not sure the exact use case you want from this, but the code you provided suggests that this attribute indicates that comments are required (duh). Because you indicated that "NO" should turn the textarea red, I attached it to know. This of course suggests that if a user clicks yes, it's ok not to add a comment. You can modify this however.
3. Added a call to the update function for onload that checks all of the comment-required inputs that are checked to see if they have a comment in the comment box.

Comment: How can i run above script on load as each is removed here?

Comment: So it needs to run on click and on load?

Comment: Yes. On load as well as on click, That's why Each was suggested. Sorry i didn't mention this before in question, i have updated question now.

Comment: $el.closest(".scope-question").find("textarea") is returning Undefined everytime. As i can see you have put both textarea and radio in one outer div but i already have design made so i could not do that. I need both in seperate divs

Comment: Then use the selector from the first fiddle. In the first example, I only change the selector. In the second, I modify the markup as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lrydh0xw/)

Your only had to remove javascript `each` function and change few selectors

Comment: Like if i want this script to run onload. 
Then how will things work? I think each will work at that time

Comment: Here I have added default selection to your 1st question Click here https://jsfiddle.net/81xy2d4g/

Comment: Thanks. So here .each is unnecessary? Like, for question 1.1 i need to red 1.4 red or vice versa?

Comment: Yes .each is unnecessay. Thinks this solves your issue

Comment: It looks your updates help a lot. Let me implement it as per validation rules  still there are some validations like not to red on 1.2 and red of 1.4 on 1.1 etc.

Comment: Take you time and get back again if you find any problem